# things happened behind the scene for unordered_map for insert

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I created an `unordered_map`, and value type is `vector<string>`, when I insert element with key `1` on the 2nd line, it seems a new `vector<string>` is created on the fly -- since I can `push_back` smoothly (when key `1` does not exists)? I tried to refer C++ reference, but cannot find an answer. Does unordered_map responsible for automatically created an instance of value type when key does not exists?

```
unordered_map<int, vector<string>> a;
a[1].push_back("Hello C++ ");
cout << a[1][0] << endl; // Hello C++ printed
```

Comment: [`std::unordered_map::operator[]:` Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at)

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear on this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at "Inserts a value_type object constructed in-place" where `value_type` is a `pair<Key, T>`

Comment: Also, if you want to get an element without causing an insertion if the key does not exist (and causing an exception in that case), take a look at the [`at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/at) method. This is specially useful with `const` maps, since `operator[]` is, obviously, non-const.

Comment: @nwp, this is exactly what I am looking for. Could you add a reply? I will mark it as answer to benefit other people.